# Can I stop receiving push notification for a particular time interval in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have an application which receives notification. In my settings page, there is an option to disable the notification during a time interval and this is user specific.

Is there any way to do it in swift?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can manage that by syncing this with your server to stop triggering push notifications during a specified time for specific user say by adding a bool field (`sendingEnabled`) to check it before sending any push notification

Answer (score 1):

Generally push notifications are initiated from a web server. (Note: Application has not control over push notification, once you register it with APNS server and your app is not in `Active` state) So web server can control it.

**But how?**

Create a web service (request) linking user (app's) setting info (regarding push notification schedule) and submit/update it on web server (user's db) whenever user changes push notification schedule in mobile app.

Your server will have complete schedule about user's push notification settings. And you will be able to manage push notification fire from server.

I think, this is only the way to control push notification.

Answer (score 0):

This can be managed by having one additional web service call, call this API at particular time and invalidate the device token from the back end. And validate when ever you want to send notification again.